# Express DNF formula as ILP constraint

Tags: boolean-logic, linear-programming

Is there any way to convert DNF formula as ILP constraint?
For example, suppose that I have the follow the following formula:

```
(x_1 and x_2 and x_3) or (not x_1 and x_2 and not x_3)
```

How to write it as ILP?

I know that it can be transformed into equisatisfiable CNF expression and then into ILP, but this can be exponential in size of clauses/variables.

Comment: Take a look at [this review](http://www.minlp.org/pdf/GBDEWOGrossmann.pdf) of the Generalized Disjunctive Programming techniques and software with links thereof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
y1<=x1
y1<=x2
y1<=x3
y1>=x1+x2+x3-2
y2<=1-x1
y2<=x2
y2<=1-x3
y2>=1-x1+x2+1-x3-2
y>=y1
y>=y2
y<=y1+y2
all variables in {0,1}
```

The result will be available in y